# Writing text to XML with XMLSerializer without escaping it

Tags: android, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

am trying to write text to an XML-File using the XMLSerializer. The text(String)-function escapes characters automatically.

Is it possible not to escape text when adding it to the xml-File?

If it is not possible, could you recommend an easy workaround without having to rewrite all of my XML creation code?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably moved along and found your own solution in the meantime but here is a possible solution. Rather than using the serializer, I directly call the underlying StringWriter to insert raw text (in my case that is well formed xml, so I want to avoid escaping the <,> marks).  Notice the serializer flush is very important to get the correct order.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
try {
    serializer.setOutput(writer);
    serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
    serializer.startTag(namespace, "destination");
    serializer.attribute(namespace, "id", String.valueOf(destinationId));
    serializer.flush();
    writer.write(DestinationContent);
    serializer.endTag(namespace, "destination");
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```